# How do you get the traditional blue map marker in your app's map in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, maps, react-native-maps, currentlocation

I have an option in my app where my user sees their current location, but it is currently represented with a pin. I would like to replace it with the pulsing blue dot that is found on both iOS and Android when you open up your phone's maps app. How can this be achieved without using a "custom image" as my map marker? It may be worth noting that I am using react-native-maps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can't get the 'standard' iOS or Android Marker to show up in your RN Maps. The next best thing to do would be to use react-native-svg

This would create a 'standard' looking marker, and what I did.

Below is an example as to how you could do this in Expo SDK 43

```
import Svg, {Path, Circle, Ellipse} from 'react-native-svg'
import MapView, { Marker } from "react-native-maps";
```

...

```
const icon = () => {
      return(
        <Svg 
          height = {20}
          width = {20}
        >
        <Ellipse
          cx="10"
          cy="10"
          rx="10"
          ry="10"
          fill="blue"
          stroke="#fff"
          strokeWidth="2"
        />
        </Svg>

        )
    }
```

...

```
<MapView>
  <Marker
     coordinate={ 
      //coordinate parameters go here
     }
  >
    <View>
      {(icon())}
    </View>
  </Marker>
 </MapView>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the react-native-map README.md file, there are detailed explanations about customizing the marker.
https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps#rendering-a-marker-with-a-custom-image

```
<Marker
  coordinate={{ latitude : latitude , longitude : longitude }}
  image={require('../assets/pin.png')}
/>
```

Comment: I didn't want to add a custom marker, I was more so curious if there was a way of changing the default from being a pin to being the blue map marker found on Apple and Google maps that senses your direction change?

Comment: It seems there's no way to set the default marker found on iOS and Android on the package.

Comment: I was afraid as such. I was curious because I see people with the marker in tutorial videos and it appears to be their default. i could never figure out how to get them.

Comment: Again, to achieve the goal, a custom maker should be used.

Comment: It'd be thankful if you can tick or accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try the showsUserLocation prop from MapView
https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md

```
<MapView
 ...
 showsUserLocation={true}
 style={{
   width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
   height: Dimensions.get('window').height
 }}
 ...
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

import Svg, {Path, Circle, Ellipse} from 'react-native-svg'

Make sure expo in package.json is at: "^44.0.0",
and react-native-svg in package.json is at: "^9.3.3",

And then place the following code within the Marker Component.

```
  <MapView style={styles.map}
  region={mapRegion}
  mapType='hybrid'
  provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
  >
  <Marker coordinate={{ latitude: mapRegion.latitude,
    longitude: mapRegion.longitude}} 
    image={require('./bluecircle.png')}
    >
    <View>
    <Svg 
    height = {20}
    width = {20}
  >
  <Ellipse
    cx="10"
    cy="10"
    rx="10"
    ry="10"
    fill="blue"
    stroke="#fff"
    strokeWidth="2"
  />
  </Svg>
    </View>
  </Marker>
  </MapView>
```